# uncheck overall radiogroup radio field during load in extjs 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, extjs, extjs4

Here the radio field in  the radio group usually select based on the previous selection. i.e., when refresh the page it automatically set the previous value. But i need to clear the over all values from radio group.

```
this.mcmAdminServiceIndicatorsRadioGroup = new Ext.form.RadioGroup({
            width: 350,
            height: 50,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'radiofield',
                    name: 'serviceIndicator',
                    fieldLabel: '',
                    inputValue: 'ADM',
                    boxLabel: 'ADM'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'radiofield',
                    name: 'serviceIndicator',
                    margin: '0 0 0 20',
                    fieldLabel: '',
                    inputValue: 'BCK',
                    boxLabel: 'BCK'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'radiofield',
                    name: 'serviceIndicator',
                    margin: '0 0 0 20',
                    fieldLabel: '',
                    inputValue: 'CKC',
                    boxLabel: 'CKC'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'radiofield',
                    name: 'serviceIndicator',
                    margin: '0 0 0 20',
                    fieldLabel: '',
                    inputValue: 'BRK',
                    boxLabel: 'BRK'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'radiofield',
                    name: 'serviceIndicator',
                    margin: '0 0 0 20',
                    fieldLabel: '',
                    inputValue: 'FMF',
                    boxLabel: 'FMF'
                }               
            ]
        });
```

am tried these three ways inside the listner of the other radio group component..

```
this.mcmTaskCategoryRadiogroup = new Ext.form.RadioGroup({
            width: 205, 
            height: 50,
            items: [
                { 
                    xtype: 'radiofield', 
                    name: 'type', 
                    inputValue: 'Customer',
                    boxLabel: 'Customer', 
                    checked: true 
                },
                { 
                    xtype: 'radiofield', 
                    name: 'type', 
                    inputValue: 'Admin',
                    boxLabel: 'Admin' 
                }
            ],
            listeners: {
                scope: this, 
                change: function(radiogroup, newValue, oldValue) { //will be trigger twice, one with both fields, and second with the new field

                    if(typeof(newValue.type) == 'string') {
                        if(newValue.type === 'Admin') {
                            this.mcmPassengerFieldSet.hide();
                            this.mcmPassengerServiceIndicatorsFieldSet.hide();
                            this.mcmAdminServiceIndicatorsFieldSet.show();
                            this.mcmRequestTypeCombobox.store.loadData([{ name: 'Admin' }], false);
                            this.mcmRequestTypeCombobox.setValue('Admin');
                            //this.mcmAdminServiceIndicatorsRadioGroup.setValue(false);


//this.mcmAdminServiceIndicatorsRadioGroup.setValue({ serviceIndicator: taskType });


this.mcmAdminServiceIndicatorsRadioGroup.items.items[0].setValue(true);
                        } else if(newValue.type === 'Customer') {
                            this.mcmPassengerFieldSet.show();
                            this.mcmPassengerServiceIndicatorsFieldSet.show();
                            this.mcmAdminServiceIndicatorsFieldSet.hide();
                            this.mcmRequestTypeCombobox.store.loadData([
                                { name: '5Star' }, 
                                { name: '5Key' },
                                { name: 'Concierge Key' }, 
                                { name: 'Focus Market' }, 
                                { name: 'Sales' }, 
                                { name: 'OA VIP' },
                                // TCS:09-24-2013 modified
                                { name: 'JL VIP' },
                                { name: 'BA VIP' },
                                { name: 'IB VIP' },
                                { name: 'QF VIP' },
                                // modification ended
                                { name: 'Other'  } 
                            ], false);
                            this.mcmRequestTypeCombobox.setValue(
                                this.mcmDisplayedRecord.get('RequestType') ? this.mcmDisplayedRecord.get('RequestType') : 'Other');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the 'checked : true' from the Customer radiofield?

David

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug of Ext JS. The below code is a reset function source code present in "Ext.form.field.Field" class.

```
reset : function(){
    var me = this;
    me.beforeReset();
    me.setValue(me.originalValue);
    me.clearInvalid();
    // delete here so we reset back to the original state
    delete me.wasValid;
```

}

**Explanation:**

The above function set the field value as actual original value of the field. This is working fine for all other types except "radio". The "checked:false" setting is also not working even though the base class for radio is "checkbox"(works fine for checkbox).

**Problem**

I think the problem is occurred after selecting any one of the options of radio/radiogroup. The radio component needs to maintain the original value properly but whenever we checked/unchecked, the original value of the radio component is changed. Thats is the reason the reset function is failed to reset the radio.

**Hack**

I did a hack for this problem. I am maintaing one more key for holding my original value of the radio and I manually set the value whenever I call the reset function. I have overriden the above function like this.

```
reset : function(){
    var me = this;
    me.beforeReset();
    me.setValue(me.initialDefaultValue);
    me.clearInvalid();
    // delete here so we reset back to the original state
    delete me.wasValid;
```

}

Now I can create a radio button something like this,

```
{xype: 'radio', name: 'Test', initialDefaultValue: false, boxLabel: 'Hello'}
```

The above solution will work fine even If you reset entire form values by calling form.reset().

Hope this help..!